# Is Windows XP standard font smoothing on by default?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, anti-aliasing

There are two font smoothing options for Windows XP: Standard and ClearText. I know the default is NOT to use ClearType, but I am wondering if "standard" is on by default in the majority of XP installation base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "Standard" is on by default. I've had to enable ClearType on every of my Windows XP installations.